# Call API success but can't get string from setter and getter

Tags: java, android

I set a Song List from database named Page Songe, click item and start another activity, I use `Intent.putExtra()` to pass the id to next Song Info page, and Song Info Page get the ID, than call `FindById` API to connect database to get song info, I use debug mode, it connects to database and gets the right data, but somehow it's just not showing on the page, is it a setter/getter issue?

Code:

```
public class SongPage extends Activity{
    //textview
    TextView ID;
    TextView artist;
    TextView year;
    TextView weeks;
    TextView songname;
    SongInfoHolder SongHolder = new SongInfoHolder();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.songpage);
        //get the item id
        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        String songID = intent.getStringExtra("itemid");
        //connection to the api
        new Connection().execute("http://192.168.1.105:3000/findById/" + songID);
        SongInfoHolder SongHolder = new SongInfoHolder();
        ID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textSongPage_ID);
        artist = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textSongPageArtist);
        year = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textSongPageYear);
        weeks = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textSongPageWeeks);
        songname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textSongPageName);

        //set text from getter
    }

    class Connection extends AsyncTask< String , String ,String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                String finalJson = buffer.toString();
                JSONObject finaObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
                //Put string into seter

                SongInfoHolder SongHolder = new SongInfoHolder();
                SongHolder.set_id(finaObject.getString("_id"));
                SongHolder.setDecade(finaObject.getString("decade"));
                SongHolder.setArtist(finaObject.getString("artist"));
                SongHolder.setSong(finaObject.getString("song"));
                SongHolder.setWeeksAtOne(finaObject.getString("weeksAtOne"));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result == null){
                ID.setText(SongHolder.get_id());
                artist.setText(SongHolder.getArtist());
                year.setText(SongHolder.getDecade());
                weeks.setText(SongHolder.getWeeksAtOne());
                songname.setText(SongHolder.getSong());
            }else {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Getter/setter:

```
public class SongInfoHolder {
    private String _id;
    private String decade;
    private String artist;
    private String song;
    private String weeksAtOne;

    public String get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(String _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public String getDecade() {
        return decade;
    }

    public void setDecade(String decade) {
        this.decade = decade;
    }

    public String getSong() {
        return song;
    }

    public void setSong(String song) {
        this.song = song;
    }

    public String getWeeksAtOne() {
        return weeksAtOne;
    }

    public void setWeeksAtOne(String weeksAtOne) {
        this.weeksAtOne = weeksAtOne;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the `onPostExecute()` method to set the data. But beware the memory leak you're making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a getter/setter issue. Issue is that you are calling an `AsyncTask` and immediately after that you try to set the values in `TextView`. By the time code which sets the text in those `TextView` is hit, data is not ready in `SongHolder` (also because you never set anything to this variable, you are using a new one in `doInBackground`) object. You need to set texts to `TextView` when the data is ready.

Add these lines in `onPostExecute` method

```
ID.setText(SongHolder.get_id());
artist.setText(SongHolder.getArtist());
year.setText(SongHolder.getDecade());
weeks.setText(SongHolder.getWeeksAtOne());
songname.setText(SongHolder.getSong());
```

Also define these `TextView` and `SongHolder` at class level, so that they can be used in `onPostExcecute` method. And don't use a new instance of `SongInfoHolder` in `doInBackground`, use one you define at class level.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new on coding but what is class level mean? 
if I  TextView ID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textSongPage_ID); in  onPostExecute method , it can not use findviewbyid , where should i define these variable ?

Comment: Class level means just after `public class SongPage extends Activity{`

Comment: I see , but I change'public class SongPage extends Activity{
    //textview
    TextView ID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textSongPage_ID);' the onPostExecute method can't find ID , and name...etc

Comment: No just `TextView ID;` and leave `ID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textSongPage_ID);` part in `onCreate`. This goes for all the `TextView`. Define at class level and initialize in `onCreate`.

Comment: Same thing goes for `SongInfoHolder SongHolder = new SongInfoHolder();` also and also remove this code from `doInBackground`.

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(String result)  still can not resolve ID , Name, artist...etc

Comment: Make the AsynTask inner class of the activity class (means remove one `}` befor `class Connection extends AsyncTask< String , String ,String> {` and add one `}` at the end of whole file)

Comment: Sorry to say but you need to learn coding and basics of java first.

Comment: yes Thank you ! but I think almost there this page ! Just the 25 day start coding :D you gave a  good direction thank you!

Comment: One more change you need to make. Remove `SongInfoHolder SongHolder = new SongInfoHolder();` from `doInBackground`. You already have this defined at class level. No need to put it in `doInBackground`

Comment: It is not work but getting better , I use debug mode , the SongHolder get NULL object , looking for what's going on ,but your direction is right

Comment: see my  last comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class SongInfoHolder {

    private String _id;
    private String decade;
    private String artist;
    private String song;
    private String weeksAtOne;
//add your constructor here .
    public SongInfoHolder(String _id,String decade,String artist,String song,String weeksAtOne {
    this._id=id;
    this.decade=decade;
    this.artist=artist;
    this.song=song;
    this.weeksAtOne=weeksAtOne

    }
    public String get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(String _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public String getDecade() {
        return decade;
    }

    public void setDecade(String decade) {
        this.decade = decade;
    }

    public String getSong() {
        return song;
    }

    public void setSong(String song) {
        this.song = song;
    }

    public String getWeeksAtOne() {
        return weeksAtOne;
    }

    public void setWeeksAtOne(String weeksAtOne) {
        this.weeksAtOne = weeksAtOne;
    }


    }
```

and then in your asynctask add this

```
SongInfoHolder SongHolder = new SongInfoHolder(finaObject.getString("_id"),finaObject.getString("decade"),finaObject.getString("artist"),finaObject.getString("song"),finaObject.getString("weeksAtOne"));
```

and your are initialising SogInfoHolder in too many places just intialise it locally once at while setting data and once while retriving data. remove SongInfoHolder from oncreate() and before that .